# Слушатель на подключение к интернету в фрагменте

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Есть фрагмент, в котором происходит загрузка из базы данных. При отключении интернета, загрузка должна прекращаться и выводиться Тоаст "Нет интернета". При включении интернета, загрузка должна автоматически возобновляться. Может кто-то помочь с решением этой задачи?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно создать функцию которая будет возвращать `LiveData<Boolean>` и подписываться на нее в любом фрагменте или активити. В случае изменения статуса вьюха будет оповещена об этом.

`Kotlin`:

```
object NetworkUtils : ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {

private val networkLiveData: MutableLiveData<Boolean> = MutableLiveData()

fun getNetworkLiveData(context: Context): LiveData<Boolean> {
    val connectivityManager =
        context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        connectivityManager.registerDefaultNetworkCallback(this)
    } else {
        val builder = NetworkRequest.Builder()
        connectivityManager.registerNetworkCallback(builder.build(), this)
    }

    var isConnected = false

    connectivityManager.allNetworks.forEach { network ->
        val networkCapability = connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(network)

        networkCapability?.let {
            if (it.hasCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET)) {
                isConnected = true
                return@forEach
            }
        }
    }

    networkLiveData.postValue(isConnected)

    return networkLiveData
}

override fun onAvailable(network: Network) {
    networkLiveData.postValue(true)
}

override fun onLost(network: Network) {
    networkLiveData.postValue(false)
}
}
```

Подписываемся:

```
    NetworkUtils.getNetworkLiveData(requireContext()).observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { isConnected ->
         // обрабатываем
    }
```

`Java`:

```
public class NetworkUtils extends ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback {

private final MutableLiveData<Boolean> networkLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();

public LiveData<Boolean> getNetworkLiveData(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        manager.registerDefaultNetworkCallback(this);
    } else {
        NetworkRequest.Builder builder = new NetworkRequest.Builder();
        manager.registerNetworkCallback(builder.build(), this);
    }

    boolean isConnected = false;

    for (Network allNetwork : manager.getAllNetworks()) {
        NetworkCapabilities capabilities = manager.getNetworkCapabilities(allNetwork);
        if (capabilities != null) {
            if (capabilities.hasCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET)) {
                isConnected = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    networkLiveData.postValue(isConnected);

    return networkLiveData;
}

@Override
public void onAvailable(@NonNull Network network) {
    networkLiveData.postValue(true);
}

@Override
public void onLost(@NonNull Network network) {
    networkLiveData.postValue(false);
}
}
```

Подписываемся:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    NetworkUtils utils = new NetworkUtils();
    utils.getNetworkLiveData(getContext()).observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), connected -> {
        if (connected) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Disconnected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Не забудьте добавить пермишены:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: Судя по доке (`NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET - Indicates that this network should be able to reach the internet.`), так можно только узнать, есть ли подключение к к-л сети, в которой **возможно** есть подключение к интернету. По идее, выяснить, есть ли реально интернет, можно лишь постоянно делая запросы на к-л сайт/IP, например DNS гугла.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб у меня в проекте это прекрасно работает

Comment: Даже в случае, если подключиться к WiFi роутера с интернетом, а потом из этого роутера выдернуть кабель, по которому соединение с интернетом происходит?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб такое не тестил. мне было достаточно чтобы работало когда вручную включаешь/выключаешь инет на устройстве

Comment: Если вдруг решите протестировать - буду рад, если расскажете о результатах) Вроде бы не должно сработать в таком случае

Comment: спасибо большое, но Kotlin  к сожалению ещё не изучал. Вы б не смогли дать ответ на JAVA?

Comment: @YevhenKhomiak обновил ответ

Comment: @Cypher большое спасибо